# Group Duality with respect to Generators and Relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, reflection

Although the following question is not phrased in the most accurate way, I would like to ask it in the same way it rushed to my mind:

"Looking at some basic examples of group theory with geometrical interpretations, such as the group of symmetries of a regular polygon ${p}$ or a regular polyhedron ${p,q}$, where the notion of Duality makes geometric sense, and using the fact that every group would be completely identified by a presentation of the form $G=<S,R>$, where $S$ and $R$ are respectively the set of generators and relations, I was wondering if there is an algebraic notion of duality of a group $G=<S,R>$, in the sense that simply the set of relations $R$ and generators $S$ swap their roles, for the dual group we obtain. Namely, could we construct a new group with presentation of the form $G^D=<R,S>$ ?"

It seems quite feasible to take the set of relations of one group as the set of generators of another. However, when it comes to the set of generators of the first group, I don't see any clear approach to use them as the set of relations!

Comment: Suppose $G = \langle x | x^2 \rangle$. What does your proposed object $G^D$ mean? (But, if you want your 'dual' group to be the group of symmetries of the respective 'dual' polyhedron - which seems like quite a reasonable request to me - then the right definition is probably simpler than you think.)

Comment: Billy, thanks for your comment.
I see your point and I tried to briefly allude to the fact that the question, at leas phrased in this way, may make no sense. However, I am hoping it would lead me to a better way of thinking, if there is any.
Looking at the group of symmetries of the dual polyhedron is actually using the geometrical duality first, and then looking at the associated algebraic structure. Meanwhile, I wish to avoid geometric interpretation as much as possible to hope for an abstract approach. However,I certainly agree is an illuminating way of thinking about the problem.

Comment: (1/2) I think my real point is: in order for such a definition to be *mathematically meaningful*, its conception needs to be *mathematically well-motivated*. You can't just say "I want duals to exist; where are they?". Better questions: what do you want $G^D$ to *do*? Or how do you want it to *look* relative to $G$? I see no mathematical *reason* to swap the generators and relations of a group (and no guarantee that it could be made to work). My geometric proposal was just something slightly more well-motivated (but, if you work through the details, you'll see it's also not very interesting).

Comment: (2/2) On the other hand, there certainly *are* some notions of duality that arose from mathematical questions, which you may be interested in looking up. A simple one would be the concept of a dual vector space (vector spaces are, of course, continuous groups too), which arises by considering functions on that space (or matrix transposition). A harder one: Pontryagin duality comes from trying to do Fourier analysis on certain groups, and crops up very naturally in a bunch of places, including e.g. the character theory of finite abelian groups.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, supposed $G=\langle S\mid R\rangle$, you somehow want to interpret $S$ as the corresponding set of some relations, using elements of $R$ as variable symbols.

Well, such an interpretation *cannot exist*, at least in its full generality, simply because $R$ can be empty without $S$ being empty (representing the free group over $S$), but if $S$ is empty, then we don't have any variable symbol to write up any relation, so $R$ also has to be empty.